# Can you identify this minifig and its set?

Tags: set-identification, clone-brands, minifigure-identification

I would like to know what set this minifigure belongs to.

[image]

Comment: The legs might be LEGO, but the rest definitely isn't. No idea what it actually is.

Answer (score 5):

The legs appear to be LEGO, the torso and head are from the old Mega Bloks Dragons series.